# i can't update ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: apt

i have issue to update my ubuntu 18.04 server when i try to do so i get these errors:

```
apt-get update
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:9 https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
  Could not connect to download.webmin.com:443 (108.60.199.109), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/InRelease  Could not connect to download.webmin.com:443 (108.60.199.109), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: "Connection timed out" indicates some kind of networking problem. Are you connected to the network? What network troubleshooting have have you already done?

Comment: i have no network issue i can ping 8.8.8.8 and google.com and also no network error i get

Comment: yes i reach them

Comment: i don't use proxy

Comment: yes i tried them all

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` again. If it still fails, then you have an ISP problem (except for the one that really doesn't exist anymore, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Let me go over the three basic troubleshooting steps that will solve most of things:

1. **Check Power** (is the modem / router turned on, is the adapter turned off (wifi), etc)
2. **Check your connections** (check cables: are they properly plugged, try re-seating, are they in the correct place, etc)
   *Some of us would have added after this to check on which side of the keyboard is the problem occurring*  :P
3. **Only then try to look further** into configurations, software, etc.

With Networking Troubleshooting
The basic idea is

1. Try to **ping your modem/router**.

example A: `ping 192.168.0.1` (whatever the IP of your gateway is)

2. If you succeed try to **ping a known IP** (example 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8)

example B:  `ping 1.1.1.1` (or whatever server you know is usually always up, (and replies))

3. If you succeed try to **ping a website** (google.com)

example C:  `ping google.com` (or whatever website you know normally is up and replies)

You are basically working your way out of the network, because if you can't even ping your gateway the problem is within your device or between.
But if you can get to outside IP's but not names, then your issue is DNS (resolving names to IP's)